# Soap request with camel cxf component 400: Bad Request

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I am using Camel-CXF to call a web-service using PAYLOAD format.

- When I call the service with a payload of 10.7 KB everything is OK
- When I call the service with a payload of 13.7 KB I can't do the call and I get this Exception

  ```
  org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '400: Bad Request' when communicating with http://...
  ```
- When I call the service with a payload of 17 KB or greater I get this Exception

  ```
  java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
  ```

The server has not any problems cause with SOAP UI each request is sent correctly.
I don't think it is a payload size problem, maybe could be a timeout problem or something else?

Comment: Unfortunately you've provided too few information to help you properly. You should really see response/logs/reasons from the server. `HTTP 400` usualy means the method or paylod is unexpected, but maybe you could inspect payload of the response if there's something more useful ..  for the `Unexpected end of file` you need to see what/why closed the connection (firewall?). I suggest you to use some monitoring tools (tcpmon?) to see what payload/headers are REALLY passed to the server and back

Comment: I saw the content passed through my port with ngrep and the difference between the requests was that in the header of the first call there is not  `Transfer-Encoding: chunked.`

Comment: If it's not chunged, then content-length should be specified. It's still not reason for http 400 or closing the connection.

Comment: Could be the content of the cxf header that contains everything is in the camel context header and is propagated to the soap request. I have no idea